# Bug in navigation bar

Tags: html

```
    <!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Science Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/home/heisenberg/Downloads/heisenberg.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Content
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
      <div class="text-black shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded"><strong>Scroll across some beautiful snaps of The Hubble telescope!!</strong></div>
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="/home/heisenberg/Downloads/bubble nebula.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">The Bubble Nebula!</h1>
        <hr class="my-4">
          <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="https://hubblesite.org/image/3725/gallery" role="button">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/home/heisenberg/Downloads/Sombero galaxy.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">The Sombrero Galaxy!</h1>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="https://hubblesite.org/contents/media/images/2003/28/1415-Image.html"  role="button">Learn more</a>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="/home/heisenberg/Downloads/heic1501a.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-4">The Pillars Of Creation!</h1>
      <hr class="my-4">
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/the-pillars-of-creation" role="button">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="spinner-border" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

"About" and "Contact"  tab in the navigation bar are not acting like links. Earlier every tab was okay. Moreover, search button is also not working properly. Please suggest some changes.
I am using bootstrap for building this website and copied the navigation code from here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Science Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/home/heisenberg/Downloads/heisenberg.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Content
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
      <div class="text-black shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded"><strong>Scroll across some beautiful snaps of The Hubble telescope!!</strong></div>
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="/home/heisenberg/Downloads/bubble nebula.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">The Bubble Nebula!</h1>
        <hr class="my-4">
          <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="https://hubblesite.org/image/3725/gallery" role="button">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/home/heisenberg/Downloads/Sombero galaxy.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">The Sombrero Galaxy!</h1>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="https://hubblesite.org/contents/media/images/2003/28/1415-Image.html"  role="button">Learn more</a>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="/home/heisenberg/Downloads/heic1501a.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-4">The Pillars Of Creation!</h1>
      <hr class="my-4">
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/the-pillars-of-creation" role="button">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

 </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
</div>
<div class="spinner-border" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you have made a small mistake here I can tell you what is it.

You have your carousel navigation buttons outside of your #carouselExampleControls div, and as they are position absolute so they are overlapping to your menu. so just put your both carousel button in the main carousel div. that's it. Find the corrected code in the snippet.

Comment: Hi jai, if this really helped you then don't forget to upvote pls